# Задержка при выводе текста

Tags: java

Пример:

**Консоль**

Консоль через 5 секунд: Привет

Консоль через 10 секунд: Привет Человек

Консоль через 15 секунд: Привет человек с Земли

Помогите сделать, если такое можно сделать.

Comment: А в чем проблема-то?

Comment: не понимаю как сделать

Comment: Что сделать? Задержку? Вывод текста?

Comment: Сам код как. Как сделать задержку вывода текста

Comment: Почему же вы даже не пробовали просто вбить свой вопрос в гугл/яндекс вместе с названием языка?

Answer (score 1):

Как самый очевидный вариант, который первый приходит в голову - усыпить тред в начале ответа.

```
Thread.sleep(randomNumber);
System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str[] = {"Привет", "Привет Человек", "Привет человек с Земли"};

for (int i=0; i <3; i++){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println( str[i] );
}
```